# C++ Operator+ Overloading of Matrix

Tags: c++, class, matrix, overloading

I am learning to build my own Matrix class and get a question on the operator+ overloading.

```
Matrix Matrix::operator+(Matrix &b)
{
    Matrix temp;
    *
    *
    *
    return temp;
}
c = a + b;
```

This works very well but I am a little concerned that is it inefficient that I declare a temporary matrix first then copy it to the final target (matrix c)? For example, below is a naive matrix add function,

```
void matrixAdd(Matrix& c, Matrix& a, Matrix& b)
{
    c[][]=a[][]+b[][];
}
```

Off course, the first one is easier to use but will the second be faster? If so, how can I improve the first one?

Comment: what are the benefits to making your own matrix class? I get the feeling the glm library does this more than adequately

Comment: @Charlie It's probably just for learning basic techniques of programming classes.

Comment: If you wish to take a look at how such a `Matrix` class could be implemented, check out my project called _Matrix_ on [GitHub](https://github.com/ForceBru/Matrix).

Comment: BTW, are you sure that the `variable[][]` syntax is correct? It looks pretty odd to me, given that `operator[]` must have exactly one argument, AFAIK.

Comment: @ForceBru My matrix class is inherited from vector<vector>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your snippet is fine with modern compilers.

They will optimise out an apparent deep copy of `temp` using a technique called *named return value optimisation*.

In other words the compiler will make the improvements in the first snippet for you, and the second one will wind up being no faster. For more details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization

Finally though, it's a good idea to change the prototype to

`Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix &b) const`

so you are able to apply the operator to `const` arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! If the matrix class is built as a library, will this make any difference?

Comment: Not at all - named return value optimisation allows us all to write much clearer code.

Comment: I have just tested both methods and found that the second on is 30 times faster than the first one.

Comment: That's likely to be due to things in the test setup, unless the default constructor is slow.